# How can I perform time range query and skip documents at a particular interval?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of 10 million documents each having a field 'timeOfReceipt' which is milliseconds, I would like to perform a range query (24 hour period) and then further filter that by skipping documents at a specified interval (10 second interval for example). The range query is simple enough I just don't understand how I can skip using an interval.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to keep track of the most recent 'timeOfReceipt' retrieved and perform a >= search on the next iteration. If timeOfReceipt is properly indexed this will be more performance than searching with a baseline time and skipping to the next unread. Note I chose >= over > in case you have multiple records with the same time with spillover into the next batch.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wish to keep this to one cursor/query for this operation here is now way to programatically iterate only a certain selection of documents for each batch you pull from the server.

The best way to achieve this would be to cache on your client side until you have all the documents you would need and then return that batch the end user. You would need to cache any leftover documents and then retrieve them at the start of the next batch.

Comment: So your suggesting to pull the initial set (24 hours of data is roughly 17000 documents) and use the cursor to walk those results throwing out the ones that are not met by the interval? Is there not a way to achieve this with aggregation or mapreduce?